# MYSQL aggregate entries when joined fields have multiple matches

Tags: mysql, join, count, sum, case

I am trying to count total answers, and total correct responses to a given question for students who might be enrolled in multiple classes with a given teacher.  I would like the results grouped by test and teacher, with duplicate students removed.

What I would like to get out of the following is:

```
test1-teacher1-6-4
test1-teacher2-3-2
```

However, the fact that student3, student4 and student5 are enrolled in different classes with teacher1 (see below) is causing them to be counted twice, so I get...

```
test1-teacher1-6-6
test1-teacher2-3-2
```

Here is all the data I am using.

Any thoughts on how to remove the duplicate students?  Thanks.

```
create database test_db;

use test_db;

drop table if exists test;
create table test(test_name varchar (50),student_name varchar(50),result varchar(50));


drop table if exists roster;
create table roster(teacher_name varchar(50),student_name varchar(50), class_name varchar(50));

insert into test values ('test1','student1','c');
insert into test values ('test1','student2','x');
insert into test values ('test1','student3','x');
insert into test values ('test1','student4','c');
insert into test values ('test1','student5','c');
insert into test values ('test1','student6','c');
insert into test values ('test1','student7','c');
insert into test values ('test1','student8','x');

insert into roster values ('teacher1', 'student1', 'class1'); 
insert into roster values ('teacher1', 'student2', 'class1'); 
insert into roster values ('teacher1', 'student3', 'class1');
insert into roster values ('teacher1', 'student4', 'class1');
insert into roster values ('teacher1', 'student5', 'class1');
insert into roster values ('teacher1', 'student6', 'class1');

insert into roster values ('teacher1', 'student3', 'class2');
insert into roster values ('teacher1', 'student4', 'class2');
insert into roster values ('teacher1', 'student5', 'class2');

insert into roster values ('teacher2', 'student6', 'class3');
insert into roster values ('teacher2', 'student7', 'class3');
insert into roster values ('teacher2', 'student8', 'class3');



use test_db;
select 
    test_name,
    r.teacher_name,
    count(distinct r.student_name) as numTested,
    sum(case
        when result = 'c' then 1
        else null
    end) as Q1correct
from
    test t
        join
    roster r ON t.student_name = r.student_name
group by t.test_name , r.teacher_name;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a sub-query to remove the duplicates from `roster`.

```
select 
    test_name,
    r.teacher_name,
    count(distinct r.student_name) as numTested,
    sum(case
        when result = 'c' then 1
        else null
    end) as Q1correct
from
    test t
        join
    (select distinct teacher_name, student_name
     from roster) r ON t.student_name = r.student_name
group by t.test_name , r.teacher_name;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a9e2/2)